# Node Q - handle array with Q

Tags: arrays, node.js, q

I have an  array of elements `var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`. What I want is to take every element, do some stuff, and take the other. I don't want the stuff to be done in parallel.

for example:

```
arr.forEach(function(d){
   //send 'd' through HTTP
   //if send is success wait 1000 resend the same.      
});
```

How can I do this with `Q` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn an array of items into a sequentially processed array of promises, you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
var Q = require('q'); 

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var lastPromise = arr.reduce(function(promise, item) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return someFunc(item);
    });
}, Q.resolve())


lastPromise.then(function() {
    console.log('some message');
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log('some error');
});
```

Here `someFunc` is processing your item say like this

```
var item = 'item1';

someFunc(item).then(function(result) {
       console.log("The task finished.");
})
.catch(function(error) {
       console.log(error);
});
```

`arr.reduce()` takes two arguments, a callback and an initial value.If you notice they passed a second argument to `reduce()`, it will now call the given callback for each element in your array. The callback gets two arguments. The first time, the first argument is the initial value and the second argument is the first element of the array. Next time, the first argument is the return value of the previous time the callback was called, and the second argument is the next element of array.

For more details on this please take a look at
https://joost.vunderink.net/blog/2014/12/15/processing-an-array-of-promises-sequentially-in-node-js